# Which is better for signal integrity in a two layer PCB? Two ground planes or one power and one ground plane?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers, signal-integrity

I am designing a two layer PCB with high speed signals with rise and fall times as low as 3ns.

I was doing some studying and learned that for better signal intergrity and EMI a good grounding strategy is critial. To lower the effects of displacment current lowering crosstalk, routing a ground element along with each high speed tracks helps. May it be a ground plane underneath or ground track along side it.
(Do correct me if I am wrong with my understanding.)

Would it be a better strategy to have both layers as ground plane? A ground plane forces a return path next to most signals.  Stitching vias make for even better return paths.

Is there any other benefits to having power and ground plane? I understand that this strategy has the advantage of creating decoupling capacitence.

EDIT:
What is meant by 2 ground planes, I actually meant Signal-Ground/Signal-Ground.
AND
What is meant by 1-power 1-ground planes, I actually meant Signal-Power/Signal-Ground.

Comment: My apologies, I am not to very familiar with the terminlogies what electronics guys term gound planes? Does ground plane mean enitre plane has only ground and no signals?

Comment: It means that the majority of the layer is given over to a plane or planes but, I guess it is ambiguously defined.

Comment: *To lower the effects of displacement current lowering crosstalk* <-- increasing crosstalk I think you mean.

Comment: @Andyaka Ehh I think you are right, I migh have had it backwards, I think. More displacement current should tighten then spread of EMI so lowering crosstalk.

Comment: More displacement current into nearby non-associated conductors means more crosstalk.

Comment: What are you putting on this PCB?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Signals from Microcontroller at frequencies upto 300Mhz going to Optocouplers going to RS422 diffrential transreciver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a 2 layer PCB is your only option: make the second layer ground and route your signals and power on the first. A proper ground/return plane is key for every signal and avoid sharing of the return path as much as possible. (A GND plane is preferable compared to a return trace)

High speed signals tend to follow underneath the signal trace, in the dielectric the energy will travel: between the two layers. Any obstacles will produce problems.

The higher the frequency, the more the return path of the signal will follow the signal trace:

[image]
<sub>Image source: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/ext/resources/article-images-2020/A-Simple-Demonstration-of-Where-Return-Current-Flows/F1.jpg</sub>

The nice thing of a 4-layer pcb is the distance between layer 1-2 and 3-4, very close. In a signal-gnd-gnd-signal configuration any inductance related to your traces will have less effect in 3D perspective compared to the much bigger distance between layer 2 and 3 and in case of a 2 layer pcb between both layers.

Inductance around traces, stopped by the gnd layers top/bottom:

[image]
<sub>Image source: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/ext/resources/Blogs/2020/What-is-Differential-Impedance-and-Why-do-We-Care/F1.jpg</sub>

Compare the distances between the layers:

4-layer:

[image]
<sub>Image source: https://www.bitweenie.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/4LayerPCB_Stackup.png</sub>

2-layer:

[image]
<sub>Image source: https://manage.pcbgogo.com/img/js/ueditor/ueditor1.4.3.3/net/upload/image/20200114/6371460255595880006009080.png</sub>

In that way I don’t believe in ground poured next to traces and pads; the effect is too small and a possible cause of trouble if not designed very carefully.

Comment: Did you generate the first 3 images? If so, then what tool did you use? On a side note; pictures do need attribution when placed in answers.

Comment: I used them from the internet. I added the attribution, sorry!

Comment: This would be a better attribution as it links to the article in which the pictures are shown: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/articles/1771-a-simple-demonstration-of-where-return-current-flows

Comment: Good point, will do next time. You already supplied the first one, the second image was changed (was initially made for another purpose, but couldn't find a good example). The other two are just build-up's.

Comment: In a Altium confrenece, I heard the host stating that adding ground tracks along side high speed signals has huge effects on signal integrity.

Comment: Do you have a link? Very interested!

Comment: Here you go : https://youtu.be/ySuUZEjARPY?t=2750

Comment: Yes nice video: some thoughts. It’s a 2-layer board without a GND under the signals. They had to lower EMI without to many changes (probably a cost issue). He put GND between couples of signals, probably differential signals traces. The thing is you don’t want to share return path, with differential pairs it’s more forgiving. But like he said not ideal. But if designed correctly, seen the circumstances, a solution with acceptable results.

Comment: In your first picture, why does the 50kHz example look like it's not on a continuum between the 1kHz and the 1MHz examples? Like, why is the green "flooding" the blue so much?

Answer (score 8):

A 2-layer PCB will be insufficient for fast signals when the design is dense using recent tiny surface-mount chips.

On a 2-layer PCB, you won't have the luxury of having a power plane and a ground plane unless the design is rather simple.

The separation between the ground plane and signal traces on a 2-layer PCB is several times larger than you'll get on a 4-layer PCB, and this negatively affects signal integrity.

In your design, you'll likely need to use series termination resistors at least on the source end of signal traces, to keep the ringing to a minimum. This will require careful measurement on a prototype board, and optimizing the part values manually.

There's always a benefit to have two reference planes, i.e. a ground and one or more power planes, or even multiple ground planes in a multi-layer design. The general idea is to "short" the planes together at AC by distributing small coupling capacitors across the board. I call it "sprinking the board" with caps. Imagine you have a spice shaker and you've shaken some 0402 capacitors on the board. Those capacitors would go between the power and ground planes, independently of any decoupling caps next to the chips. These "sprinkles" will provide the distributed capacitance needed to make the power and ground planes equally good at routing return currents of fast signals.

Comment: Yes the design is rather simple. But does have a quite a few high speed traces. Your Idea of sprinkling decaps seems intriguing. I like it.